# how to show seekbar position and timer in mediaplayer when close activity and comeback

Tags: android, media-player, seekbar

I use the service in media player and when play song show notification in status bar .
i want when close activity play music and song play in background and when comeback this activity show seek bar position and timer .
but when i com back seek bar and all view reset.
please help ?